# Close the service from the library only when the entire app goes to the background

Tags: android

I searched a lot in the net about it, the solutions are based on `onPause` and `onDestroy`. I want to give a library to a developer who just needs to paste a few lines of code from the library in his app which will enable the developer to create a service and destroy it when his entire app is in the background.

Does the Android OS send some kind of signals or intents when the app or the activity is changed (other than onPause or onStop method), so that i can catch that in a broadcast receiver from my library and do some actions.

Comment: look my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574125/how-to-determine-if-android-app-is-currently-in-use/21574600#21574600

Answer (score 0):

If you know the package name of your app, try this (put this following snippet in the onCreate method of your app):

```
  ActivityManager am= (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Then,

```
 boolean exit = false;
 while(!exit)
 { 
  List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
  ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
 if(!componentInfo.getPackageName().equals("Your package name"))
 {
  //Do your work here
  exit = true;
 }
}
```

When you start your app, this will be put into **componentInfo**. The **taskInfo.get(0).topActivity** will return the activity in the foreground. Hence you can know that your app has gone to the **background** by comparing package using the second code snippet.

Note:Put this second code snippet in an *Asynctask* so that the checking of whether the app has started can be done in the background.